# What could cause -->TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, sklearn-pandas, kaggle

trying my hands on the kaggle titanic competition;

I ran the code below and got the error message in the title. What could I be doing wrong?

```
# run decision tree model on the data and printing the accuracy
from sklearn import tree

decision_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3)
model = decision_tree.fit(trainData, trainLabels)

accuracy = model.score(valData, valLabels) * 100
accuracy
```

Comment: Since you don't show a call to `float` in your code, it's hard to say.  But usually it's caused by forgetting to put the `()` after a function name to make a call into it.

Comment: You should provide at the very least the entire error traceback (it contains valuable information about where the error is coming from).  You should strive to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).